# Access to inner array in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is JSON. I want to get value of 'localId'. How to do this ?

```
"orderGroupByBin": [
{
  "buyerBin": "7401",
  "buyerCompanyName": {
    "nameRu": "Привет"", 
  },
  "orderGroupByAccount": [
    {
      "internalAccountId": 4523642387,
      "localId": 85352311765,
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: If `x` is the outermost object (you've only shown the contents of it), then `x.orderGroupByBin[0].orderGroupByAccount[0].localId`. Of course, I don't have any way of knowing whether they'll always be the first entries in their respective arrays...

Answer (score 0):

If your variable is called `object` you can simply access it through

```
object.orderGroupByBin[0].orderGroupByAccount[0].localId
```